# Polymer 1 paper-radio-group issue

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying to bind a set of `paper-radio-button` using a `paper-radio-group`. Here is my code in `Index.html`:

```html
<paper-card heading="Radio button group binding">
  <div class="card-content">
    <h4>Which writer you like the most?</h4>
    <paper-radio-group>
      <radio-group-binder data='[{"name": "William Shakespere", "value": "ws"}, {"name": "Arthur Conan Doyale", "value": "cd"}, {"name": "Shidney Sheldon", "value": "ss"}]'>
      </radio-group-binder>
  </paper-radio-group>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

My custom element looks like this:

```
<template>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
     <paper-radio-button name="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</paper-radio-button>
  </template>
```

Data is binding fine but I can select more than one radio button inside the group. What am I doing wrong here?

I attached a screenshot of how it is behaving now. I need to able to only select one option at a time in this `radio-button-group`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `attr-for-selected` to refer to the attribute it needs to group.

```
<paper-radio-group attr-for-selected="name">
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I applied the above but it still the same. Here is the screencast: http://screencast.com/t/21z9N2Cr

Answer (score 0):

Actually `selected={{button}}` will store the name/value of the selected radio-button into variable button. so that you can use it later if you want. As far as your question "Selecting only one radio button inside the radio group," I did few change like below and it worked for me. Please give it a try:

Custom element:

```
<dom-module id="radio-group-binder">
<template>
 <paper-radio-group selected="{{button}}" attr-for-selected="name">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
     <paper-radio-button name="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</paper-radio-button>
  </template>
 </paper-radio-group>
</template>
```

Index.html:

```
 <radio-group-binder data={{data}}></radio-group-binder>
    <script>
   var data = [{"name": "William Shakespere", "value": "ws"}, {"name": "Arthur Conan Doyale", "value": "cd"}, {"name": "Shidney Sheldon", "value": "ss"}];
   document.querySelector('radio-group-binder').data = data; 
    </script>
```

---

You may need add "selected" in both the places. Can you try something like below?

```
<radio-group-binder selected="{{button}}" data= yourdata....    

<paper-radio-group selected="{{button}}" attr-for-selected="name">
```

Comment: What to pass for {{button}} variable? I have <paper-radio-group> defined in a custom element and it is referenced in my index.html as <paper-radio-group attr-for-selected="name"><radio-group-binder data='[{"name": "William Shakespere", "value": "ws"}, {"name": "Arthur Conan Doyale", "value": "cd"}, {"name": "Shidney Sheldon", "value": "ss"}]'></radio-group-binder></paper-radio-group>. Sorry for my beginner level understanding here.

Comment: I have edited the the updated answer., check if that works. as far as selected={{button}} you don't need to pass anything., it will store the selected radio button value/name inside button variable i guess. So that you can use that at later. I have moved paper-radio-group from index.html into your custom element template and it worked.

Comment: Hi Srikanth, putting <paper-radio-group> inside the custom element solved my problem. Thanks for showing me the way. Now I am trying to extend the functionality but I am not able to make that. If you have time, please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609908/polymer-1-0-paper-radio-group-selection-how-to-get-selected-item and suggest me what wrong I am doing. Thanks again for your help.