# Polymer 1.0 paper-radio-group selection - how to get selected item

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253285/get-multiple-values-of-selected-paper-radio-button) but seems like it is doing nothing for me. I have Polymer 1.0.

Only change I made from the solution is to put the `observers` inside `data` property and made is "not protected". I got this idea from [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group/issues/8).

Initially I used the exact approach as in Ricky's solution but that didn't work for me either.

Here is how my custom element looks like:

```html
<dom-module id="radio-group-binder">
  <template>
        <paper-radio-group class="layout vertical" selected-item="[[selectedItem]]">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
                <paper-radio-button name="{{item.model}}" model$="[[item.model]]" price$="[[item.price]]"><span>[[item.model]]</span> <div class="paper-font-caption"><span>[[item.price]]</span> SEK</div></paper-radio-button>
          </template>
        </paper-radio-group>
        <paper-item><span>[[model]]</span></paper-item>
        <paper-item><span>[[price]]</span></paper-item>
  </template>
  <script>
      (function () {
          'use strict';

          Polymer({
              is: 'radio-group-binder',

              properties: {
                  data: {
                      type: Array,
                      notify: true,
                      observers: ['selectedItemChanged(selectedItem)']
                  },

                  price: {
                      type: String,
                      notify: true
                  },

                  model: {
                      type: String,
                      notify: true
                  }
              },

              
              selectedItemChanged: function (el) {
                  this.price = el.getAttribute('price');
                  this.model = el.getAttribute('model');
              },
          });
      })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If I have understood right, then variables like `[[model]]` and `[[price]]` under each `paper-item` should get replaced by selected values.

I tried an alert inside the `selectedItemChanged` function to check whether it is at least being called but I got none.

Again, in [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group/issues/8) post I noticed that `Polymer version 1.0.2` is mentioned and this a fix has been introduced here. Is this the issue I am facing? If so, how can I upgrade to this version? If this not the case then please let me know what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `observers` field for a property. You either have to use a single `observer` property (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks)) or a an `observers` field on the "class" itself (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#multi-property-observers)):

```
properties: {
  data: {
    type: Array,
    notify: true,
  },
},
observers: ['selectedItemChanged(selectedItem)']
```